# join list with separator

Tags: lists

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a command that takes some kind of list and joins it with some separator in between each entry.

For example, given something like:

```
parameters:
first
second with spaces
third

separator:
·
```

I'd want it to output:

```
first · second with spaces · third
```

With the spacing around the separator.

Perhaps this is more trouble than it's worth. Mainly it'd be to deal with the hassle of having to keep repasting the `·` character appropriately over any slight modification.

---

Otherwise, maybe I can leverage an environment, such as `points`, to join the `\item`s with `·` on the interior? I don't mind if it ends up being more typing, at least it'd be easier to manage and I wouldn't have to keep repasting the separator over any slight modification, since each entry would correspond to an independent `\item`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on `expl3`s `clist`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_jorge_list_clist
\clist_new:N \l_jorge_tmp_clist
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \usemylist { m }
  {
    \clist_use:Nn \l_jorge_list_clist { #1 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \setmylist { m }
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_jorge_list_clist { #1 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \formatlist { m m }
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_jorge_tmp_clist { #1 }
    \clist_use:Nn \l_jorge_tmp_clist { #2 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setmylist{first, second with spaces, third}

\begin{document}
\usemylist{.}

\formatlist{foo,bar,baz}{ FOOBAR }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have multiple of these lists, should I just keep doing `\setmylist` before each `\usemylist`? Any way to combine the two to make it less tedious? If not, no big deal.

Comment: I accidentally hit enter before I finished typing my comment. It's updated.

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña updated with both a local adhoc variant and a variant to save a list first.

Comment: That works beautifully. Thank you very much!